Paste driver via Script doesn't work
The problem is that my custom property doesn't seem to control the new copy location influence at all. What is the reason?
Blender says in the debug layer:

Can't edit driven number value, see driver editor for the driver setup.

def execute(self, context):
    ARMATURE = bpy.data.objects[ARMATURE_NAME]
    root_bone = ARMATURE.pose.bones["root"]

    # Create new Copy Location Constraint
    copy_loc_constraint = ik_bone.constraints.new(type='COPY_LOCATION')
    copy_loc_constraint.target = ARMATURE
    copy_loc_constraint.subtarget = fk_bone_name
    copy_loc_constraint.head_tail = 0

    # Copy driver from the custom property of the root bone in the new constraint

    if root_bone.id_data.animation_data:
        for driver in root_bone.id_data.animation_data.drivers:
            if driver.data_path == 'pose.bones["root"]["Copy Location Influence"]':
                new_driver = copy_loc_constraint.driver_add("influence")
                new_driver.driver = driver.driver.copy()

